# Can you cast cantrips normally with the magic initiate?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, spellcasting, cantrips

If you choose the magic initiate feat you get 2 cantrips and a 1st level spell. Can you cast normally or do you need to take a rest between casting the cantrips

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem well enough for a green check?

Answer (score 12):

#### They can be cast at will.

Magic Initiate states:

> You learn two cantrips of your choice from that class's spell list.

The restriction on casting once per day is placed only on the 1st level spell, in the following bullet:

> - In addition, **choose one 1st-level spell** from that same list. You learn **that spell** and can cast **it** at its lowest level. Once you cast **it**, you must finish a long rest before you can cast **it** again using this feat.

"It" throughout this bullet refers exclusively to the 1st level spell you chose when you took the feat. And the rules for cantrips state:

> A cantrip is a spell that can be cast at will, without using a spell slot and without being prepared in advance.